# Как предотвратить повреждение кириллицы в gulp

Tags: gulp

Доброго дня. При прогоне JS и CSS файлов через gulp повреждается весь кириллический текст и он превращается в это: "ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿". Проблема в самом gulp'е, потому что я отключал все плагины и кириллица повреждалась просто при прогоне через pipe. Установка кодировки в явном виде через charset ситуации не изменила.

Судя по результату, у меня есть подозрения, что дело в том, что на каждый кириллический символ отводится 1 байт, вместо положенных двух.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Писать свои файлы в кодировке utf-8.